# What is the name of this short sci-fi award winning film on YouTube, in which robots are exterminating humans but one robot kept a little girl?

Tags: story-identification, robots, soft-sci-fi, short-film

Looking for the name of this short film released around 2013 maybe.

So basically the story is that the robots invaded and destroyed the humans but one girl (baby at the time) was found and kept alive by a robot and grows up with them … the robots go out to search for (and presumably exterminate) any survivors. Cassie asks to go with them to find other humans like her but the robot she’s close with says no but I think either reluctantly agrees or she follows him anyways.

They eventually come across a human and he’s hostile towards the robot and tells Cassie she’s one of them (a human) and not to trust a robot. They get into a heated fight with Cassie stepping in front of the robot to protect him from the human. The robot says there are many more like him but no one like Cassie. She’s special because she’s alive, and tells her to let the human attack him because he’ll resort to attacking Cassie too if she doesn’t move away. She refuses and when the man sees she’s going to protect the robot at the cost of her life, he attacks her, but the robot picks up a scorpion from the ground and throws it at him and the scorpion stings him and he dies. They continue their search to find more humans.

Comment: There are many very high quality original short SF films made by DUST.They started posting them to YouTube seven years ago. May have made them earlier. https://m.youtube.com/@watchdust/videos